# How to customize thumb in range slider

Tags: flutter, widget, material-design, rangeslider

[It is my desired output][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/h1rqE.png
I am working with flutter. I use Range Slider widget to select a value range. But  can't customize its slider thumb as shown in my image. How can  do this without using any package.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
import "package:flutter/material.dart";

void main() {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const MaterialApp(home: MyWidget());
  }
}

class MyWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyWidget({super.key});

  @override
  State<MyWidget> createState() => _MyWidgetState();
}

class _MyWidgetState extends State<MyWidget> {
  RangeValues values = const RangeValues(0, 10);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
        child: SliderTheme(
          data: const SliderThemeData(
            rangeThumbShape: CircleThumbShape(),
          ),
          child: RangeSlider(
            max: 100,
            values: values,
            onChanged: (RangeValues value) {
              values = value;
              setState(() {});
            },
            activeColor: Colors.green,
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class CircleThumbShape extends RangeSliderThumbShape {
  const CircleThumbShape({this.thumbRadius = 10.0});

  final double thumbRadius;

  @override
  Size getPreferredSize(bool isEnabled, bool isDiscrete) {
    return Size.fromRadius(thumbRadius);
  }

  @override
  void paint(
    PaintingContext context,
    Offset center, {
    required Animation<double> activationAnimation,
    required Animation<double> enableAnimation,
    required SliderThemeData sliderTheme,
    bool? isDiscrete,
    bool? isEnabled,
    bool? isOnTop,
    TextDirection? textDirection,
    Thumb? thumb,
    bool? isPressed,
  }) {
    final Canvas canvas = context.canvas;

    final Paint fillPaint = Paint()
      ..color = Colors.green
      ..style = PaintingStyle.fill;

    final Paint borderPaint = Paint()
      ..color = Colors.white
      ..strokeWidth = 4
      ..style = PaintingStyle.stroke;

    canvas
      ..drawCircle(center, thumbRadius, fillPaint)
      ..drawCircle(center, thumbRadius, borderPaint);
  }
}
```